# SSRS : How to "not have" a footer after first page?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I need to display a piece of information on the very first page of my report.

This piece of information has to be at the very bottom of the report (why I choosed a footer).

It will have a height of approx 3 inches, which is considerate.

I want the footer to be gone after the first page because I want to have those 3 inches back to display data.

For more context, the report is a "bill" where we have a table in the body that displays everything that you purchased. The "footer" part is where we put the banking information.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Search option, footer on first page. or you may set visibility property to true false based on page number.

Comment: You cannot set footer visibility based on page number. You can, however, create a rectangle in the footer and set the rectangle's visibility based on the page number. But the footer still take some height in the page...

Comment: @Dominic I'm facing the same issue and till now i don't get any answer...if u solve it please inform me and post the solution

Comment: @jozef I actually ended up changing the whole design of the report to include a front page with a summary of the invoice with a simulated footer (which is only a rectangle on the first page) and then adding my invoice detail on the other pages, with no footer at all. I don't think there is any way to achieve what I first requested.

Comment: @DominicGoulet first thanks for replying....mainly I'm asking about hiding the size taken by the footer..i need to show it only in last page and hide the footer size taken in other pages to benifit from report size