# SSRS : How to “not have” a footer after first page?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I need to display a piece of information on the very first page of my report.

This piece of information has to be at the very bottom of the report (why I choose a footer).

It will have a height of approx 3 inches, which is considerate.

I want the footer to be gone after the first page because I want to have those 3 inches back to display data.

For more context, the report is a "bill" where we have a table in the body that displays everything that you purchased. The "footer" part is where we put the banking information.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

I'm asking about hiding the size taken by the footer..i need to show it only in last page and hide the footer size taken in other pages to benefit from report size

Note: This same question at [Existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012192/ssrs-how-to-not-have-a-footer-after-first-page) but no approved answers and i have exactly the same scenario which i am trying to resolve but was din't find any solutions.

Comment: As you have seen and read footer/header can't be completely removed they can be hidden(by creating some placeholder inside it and then set the visibility of the placeholder) or not displayed on certain pages(first or last). However if you are exporting to excel then you can go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103771/ssrs-rdl-header-and-footer-removal-from-specific-pages)

Comment: If footer can't be removed any solution "to ensure certain content always comes completely on the first page near to bottom of the page" is also welcome. The solution should also ensure  any content above this mandatory content which does not fit should move to next page.